# .NET 6.0 console app hangfire recurring job with dependency injection for services used

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-6.0, hangfire

I am trying to create a console app that schedules a recurring job with hangfire that will run a method from a service we made. This service is imported via a nugget we made for this library. It has been a struggle to get this running. I now face the next error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'AdminService'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.
```

We can use this service perfectly fine in a webapi project we use elsewhere. So I am certain something is wrong with the way I have set up either Hangfire or the dependency Injection. I think hangfire runs outside of the DI context it needs or something and can not pass on the needed injections when it tries to use the service. I have followed both official hangfire documentation as well as online resources (guides, SO, ...).

In my main of my program.cs I have the following code

```
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddAccountLib("ConnString"); // This takes care off all DI needs for the library nugget we use.
                    services.AddHangfireServer();
                    services.AddHangfire((provider, globalConfig) =>
                    {
                        globalConfig.UseSqlServerStorage(ConnString)
                            // Create a custom job activator in order to use the ASP.net core default Di container
                            .UseActivator(new HangfireActivator(provider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()));
                    });

                    services
                    .AddSingleton<Executor, Executor>()
                    .BuildServiceProvider()
                    .GetService<Executor>()
                    .Execute(); // Run the application
                })
                .Build();

            host.Run();
```

The HangFireActivator has the following code:

```
using Hangfire;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Infrabel.Account.JobScheduler
{
    public class HangfireActivator : JobActivator
    {
        private IServiceScopeFactory _container;

        public HangfireActivator(IServiceScopeFactory container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public override object ActivateJob(Type type)
        {
            using var scope = _container.CreateScope();

            var b = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(type);

            return scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(type);
        }
    }
}
```

The Executor code:

```
public class Executor
    {
        private readonly IAdminService _adminService;
        public Executor(IAdminService adminService)
        {
            _adminService = adminService;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            try
            {
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                    .UseSqlServerStorage(ConnString);

                RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Prune update MFA backups", () => _adminService.PruneOtpBackups(), "*/2 * * * *"); // Run every 2 minutes
                using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hangfire Server started. Press any key to exit...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, "An error occured!");
                throw;
            }
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }
    }
```

I can debug through the constructor of the executor and I can see there that the admin service is filled in correctly. But when the job is scheduled I get the error. Can anybody point out to me what I am doing wrong here?